# Can not display all column from a table

Tags: magento2, php, database, sql

I have a table name my_cars. There are 4 column in my table. I create collection, model, recourse model,controller and block. And i can display data from my table. But all column of data not displaying.
[image]

car Id , Manufacturer  and created at are  displaying in phtml. but Model are not displaying.
[image]

My Model\Hello.php:

```
<?php

namespace Codilar\Helloworld\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Hello extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Codilar\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello');
    }

}
```

My ResourceModel\Hello.php

```
<?php

namespace Codilar\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Hello extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('my_cars', 'car_id '); //my_cars is table of module
    }
}
```

My ResourceModel\Hello\collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Codilar\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Codilar\Helloworld\Model\Hello',
            'Codilar\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello'
        );
    }
}
```

My Block\Hello.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @package     magento2
 * @author      Codilar Technologies
 * @license     https://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0 Open Software License v. 3.0 (OSL-3.0)
 * @link        https://www.codilar.com/
 */

namespace Codilar\HelloWorld\Block;


use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_filesystem;
 
     public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
          \Codilar\HelloWorld\Model\HelloFactory $HelloFactory
          )
     {
          parent::__construct($context);
          $this->_HelloFactory = $HelloFactory;
     }
 
     public function getResult()
     {
          $post = $this->_HelloFactory->create();
          $collection = $post->getCollection();
          return $collection;
     }
}
```

My Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Codilar\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Codilar\Helloworld\Model\HelloFactory;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $_pageFactory;
 
     public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
          \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
          )
     {
          $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
          return parent::__construct($context);
     }
 
     public function execute()
     {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
        //   echo "Module Created Successfully";
     }
}
```

Not Only for this table but also  i checked another table its just display ID,Name,Created at ,updated at.
without those 4 column there is not data displaying in view page.
My view\frontend\layout\helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Codilar\HelloWorld\Block\Hello" name="helloworld" template="Codilar_HelloWorld::hello.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My view\frontend\templates\Hello.phtml

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Created At</th>
          <th colspan="2">Action</th>
     </tr>
 
     <?php
          $collection = $block->getResult();
          foreach($collection as $item){
     ?>
     <tr>
          <td><?php echo $item->getData('car_id'); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $item->getData('manufacturer'); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $item->getDate('model'); ?></td>
     
          <td><?php echo $item->getData('created_at'); ?></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('crud/index/edit').'id/'.$item->getData('post_id'); ?>" class="action primary">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('crud/index/delete').'?id='.$item->getData('post_id'); ?>" class="action primary">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Can anyone give any solution for This problem?
If can i will be glad for this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo by your side at this line `<td><?php echo $item->getData('model'); ?></td>`. Hope, it's gonna work now.You wrote `getDate` instead of `getData`. :)